# Facebook Like button error

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm having some problems with my like button. Used Open Graph Object Debugger and no errors were found.

The button still doesn't work.
When you click "Like" it will turn into a red text "error", saying "Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later."

**Note:** the likes came from the link I've posted on Facebook, share button **is** working.

My site: [https://googledrive.com/host/...](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5xC4hGUOYsGNUpfWmJIdTZqX0k)

Comment: Seems to be working for me, http://prntscr.com/3tbdbz

Comment: @AdamAzad Have you liked it yet? its not working for me it turns to a red error message.

Comment: You didn't mention this back then, I noticed it. I believe you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @AdamAzad ok i'll try to make one. tnx